# Vue 3 Compositions API ref in v-for

Tags: vuejs3

Hej!
I'm trying to improve my due skills. I decided to make a simple dice game but I'm failing at the beginning.
I have two components. The Main Game and a dice component. In the main App component, I include the dice component and iterate over it 5 times to create 5 dices. I also add a button to roll all the dices:

```
<template>
  <div class="center">
    <Dice v-for="(dice, i) in 5" ref="diceChildren" :initialNumber="i" />
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <button @click="rollDice">Würfeln</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Dice from './components/Dice.vue'

const diceChildren = ref([]);
const rollDice = () => {
  console.log(diceChildren);
}
</script>
```

I followed the official instructions here: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for and I expected a filled array with dice refs but the diceChildren array is empty.

I need the reference to the dices to roll the dice and to get rolled number.
The get things completed, this is the code of the dice component:

```
<template>
  <div class="dice">
    <img class="dice-image" :src="getImagePath()" alt="Bild eines Würfels"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineProps, ref } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  initialNumber: Number,
});
const number = ref(props.initialNumber + 1);

const rollDice = () => {
  number.value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1)
}

const getImagePath = () => `dice_${number.value}.png`;

defineExpose({
  rollDice,
});
</script>
```

Thank you so much for help. I exhausted many hours hitherto.

I also tried to take the refs insight template:

```
<template>
  <div class="center">
    <template v-for="(dice, i) in 5" ref="diceChildren" />
       <Dice :initialNumber="i" />
    </template>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <button @click="rollDice">Würfeln</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Currently (Vue 3 version 3.2.31) there is a [bug](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/5525) in Vue when using template `ref` in `v-for` (only in `script setup` I believe)

Comment: Ohhh, I'm using version 3.2.31. That will be so annoying! Is that only for this Version? So can I downgrade to 3.2.30 and it's going to work?

Comment: I tried with all Versions down to 3.2.25. No Version is working.
I looked insight the Vue-Dev-Tools and there is diceChildren array filled with all the dices. So I believe that I'm wrong in consuming the variable.

Comment: I actually don't know and have no time to check. You can try to test in in linked stackblitz reproduction example. Personally I would go with the provided workaround right now...

Comment: Thank you! The workaround of lidlanca is working!